# Binary search using recursion goes into an infinite loop

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search

I am new to python so I don't know if I'm missing something obvious (like for example a colon or a period somewhere).

I'm trying to make this binary search algorithm work, but if I pass a list larger than 3 elements the programme goes into an infinite recursion braking and the maximum set in python.

base cases work fine.

[] and [element1] lists go through.

[element1, element2, element3, ... , element99] get stuck...

Here's the code:

```
def binsearch(pylist, element):
    if len(pylist) == 0:
        return False
    elif len(pylist) == 1 and pylist[0] == element:
        return True
    else:
        mid = len(pylist) / 2 - 1
        if element > pylist[mid]:
            binsearch(pylist[mid:], element)
        else:
            binsearch(pylist[:mid], element)
```

Thanks.

Comment: This could probably help you : https://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/SortSearch/TheBinarySearch.html

Comment: Think about what happens if you run `binsearch([1], 2)`.

Comment: Nothing obvious to me. In most cases the Python interpreter would diagnose flaws like the ones you mention anyway (but not always of course). Advice: Get hold of a development environment (IDE) that makes it possible to set breakpoints so that you can examine the contents of variables in your program, or simply put temporary *print* statements in so that you can deduce where your reasoning has gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

We obviously have to assume that the data is sorted, otherwise binary search is pretty pointless. Firstly, you were missing the case of when the element equals the pivot itself:

```
if element == pylist[mid]:
```

Also, in this block:

```
elif len(pylist) == 1 and pylist[0] == element:
    return True
```

You don't handle the case where you have one element left and it's *not* the element you want, in which case you should return False.

Below is the fully corrected code:

```
def binsearch(pylist, element):
    pylist = sorted(pylist) # Just to be sure
    if len(pylist) == 0:
        return False    

    if len(pylist) == 1:
        if pylist[0] == element:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        mid = len(pylist) // 2
        if element == pylist[mid]:
            return True
        elif element > pylist[mid]:
            return binsearch(pylist[mid:], element)
        else:
            return binsearch(pylist[:mid], element)
```

There is certainly room to make this code more efficient, but this is just correcting the code as it was given.

Answer (score 0):

Ok done. Had to make a bubble sort function to sort a random list without the set() function.

```
def binsearch(pylist, element):
    if len(pylist) == 0:
        return False
    else:
        v_mid = len(pylist) // 2
        if pylist[v_mid] == element:
            return True
        else:
            if element > pylist[v_mid]:
                return binsearch(pylist[v_mid + 1:], element)
            else:
                return binsearch(pylist[:v_mid], element)
```